# Google App Engine Instance is abruptly shutting down on Standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-firestore

We are using Google App Engine to ingest large amount of data to Google Cloud FireStore with below configuration:

Basic scaling
instance_class: B4

basic_scaling:
  instances: 1

The overall data ingestion 0f 20GB takes around 1.5 hours. But we have noticed that some time after an hour, instance is abruptly shutting down with below error:

```
Container terminated on signal 9.
```

As per this documentation, basic scaling can serve he request up to 24 hours.

We can not see any more details in the logs as well. Also checked the memory usage, B4 has 1024 MB and the app is only utilising up to 700 MB.

If anyone has faced this kind of error, your input would be valuable!

Comment: is this ingest process triggered by a task or a request? does the service receive other kinds of requests/tasks or is it a dedicated service? if it does it could be that the other processes fail and bring down the machine with them.

Comment: We are triggering this job through cloud scheduler. We checked its logs as well. But did not find that it is terminating the connection.

Comment: It looks like you are hitting 60 minutest timeouts. Can you provide more details about your configuration and yaml file?

Answer (score 3):

Although the instance has 1024MB, the Operating System also needs some of that space - I guess that's why it shuts down. It's out of memory.

Comment: We reduced the memory usage and only utilised up to 350MB, but still instance is abruptly terminated.

Comment: can you increase logging to check what happens before the `signal 9`?